# How to construct a design matrix for coxph with pspline term?

Tags: r, survival, prediction, cox-model, splines

I am wondering how to reconstruct the design matrix for a `coxph()` model with a `pspline()` term. For example, if I fit the following model,

```
fit <- coxph(Surv(t,delta) ~ pspline(x,df=0))
```

how can I calculate the linear predictor by hand for a given value of $x$?

Formally, I am modeling $h(t|x) = h_0(t)\cdot e^{(X^\intercal\beta)}$, and I want to know how to calculate $X$ or $X^\intercal\beta$ by hand. I can't find detailed documentation of how the design matrix is constructed when the `pspline()` term is used.

As for why I care, I am running a large set of new predictions from a `coxph()` object with a `pspline()` term. I have stored the cumulative hazard $H_0(t)$ and want to be able to calculate $H_0(t)\cdot e^{(X^\intercal\beta)}$ efficiently. I'm finding that using

```
predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(x=x.new), type='lp')
```

is very inefficient! 
Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you submit the following in R

```
> pspline
```

you will see the details of this function and how the design matrix is constructed via the `spline.des()` function from the 'splines' package.

From there, you can create `new.pspline(newx, x)` function that uses the actual `x` variable values to determine the arguments for the underlying `spline.des()` function, but then output the design matrix corresponding to `newx` values.

For example,

```
new.pspline <- function(newx,x){ 
    df = 4; nterm = 2.5 * df; degree = 3; eps = 0.1; Boundary.knots = range(x); nterm = round(nterm)
    dx <- (Boundary.knots[2] - Boundary.knots[1])/nterm
    knots <- c(Boundary.knots[1] + dx * ((-degree):(nterm - 1)), Boundary.knots[2] + dx * (0:degree)) 
    xx <- spline.des(knots, newx, degree + 1, outer.ok = TRUE)$design
    xx <- xx[, -1, drop = FALSE]
    xx
}
```